# Laravel whereHas with polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel 5.8. I have a table `cats`:

```
id | name
---------
1  | jim
2  | mary
```

and a table `colors`:

```
id | color
----------
1  | white
2  | black
```

I am using a polymorphic relationship to attach colors to cats (and other creatures). I have a `colorables` table:

```
id | color_id | colorable_id | colorable_type
---------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | 2            | 'App\Cat'
```

and in my `Cat` model I have

```
public function colors()
{
  return $this->morphToMany('App\Color', 'colorable');
}
```

I have this controller code to get all cats of a given color:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $cats = new Cat;
  if ($request->has('color')) {
    $color = $request->color;
    $cats->whereHas('colors', function ($query) use ($color) {
      $query->where('color_id', $color);
    });
  }
  return $cats->get();
}
```

But it's returning all cats irrespective of their color.

Comment: is `$request->has('color')` false?

Comment: @TsaiKoga No, it's got a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `new Cat` to `Cat::query()`:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $cats = Cat::query();
  if ($request->has('color')) {
    $color = $request->color;
    $cats->whereHas('colors', function ($query) use ($color) {
      $query->where('color_id', $color);
    });
  }
  return $cats->get();
}
```

or still use `new`, but assign to variable when you query:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $cats = new Cat;
  if ($request->has('color')) {
    $color = $request->color;
    $cats = $cats->whereHas('colors', function ($query) use ($color) {
      $query->where('color_id', $color);
    });
  }
  return $cats->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring cats to be a new object and then querying it with a conditional.  Try this instead

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $color = $request->has('color') : $request->get('color') : null;
  $cats = Cat::when($color, function ($query) use ($color) {
      $query->where('color_id', $color);
    })->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use laravel when() method to make your code more readable, your code should look like this.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $cats = Cat::query();

    $query->when($request->has('color'), function ($q) {
        return $q->whereHas('colors', function ($query) use ($request->color){
             $query->where('color_id', $color);
        }
    });

    return $query->get();
}
```